# TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable (numpy image)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am getting the error TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable My code is:

```
    def show_img(self,img):
        image = img
        print(image.shape)
        for i in range (len(image)):
            image= Image.fromarray(image[i].astype(np.uint8))
            image.show()
```

```
Image.shape = (8, 1080, 1920, 3)
```

Comment: what is the type of `img`? where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you modified the image.

So if image has shape `(8,1080,1920,3)`, you set `image=image[0]` in the first iteration. So now image has shape `(1080,1920,3)`. Then, in 2nd iteration, `image=image[1]` makes it shape `(1920,3)`, then in 3rd iteration, `image=image[2]` makes it shape `(3,)`, and then 4th iteration would fail any way, since `image=image[3]` is impossible with a length 3 array.

But in reality, it fails before the 4th iteration, because `.show` surely expect at least a 2d array, and after the 3rd iteration, you don't have that.

### Solution

```py
def show_img(self,img):
    image = img
    print(image.shape)
    for i in range (len(image)):
        thisImage = Image.fromarray(image[i].astype(np.uint8))
        thisImage.show()
```

(Not sure it'll work, since I know nothing neither of your image, nor of tht `.show` method. But at least, it will not fail for the same reason, and in the worst case, you'll can ask the next question :-))